# Searching a Vector for a String

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a way to search a vector for a string inputed by the user. No idea how to start. Once I find the string I have to remove its index  and print the rest of the strings in the index.

```
void addNames(vector<string>& names)
{
 names.push_back("Seppi");
 names.push_back("Farrell");
 names.push_back("Burton");
}

void print(vector<string> names)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
     {
      cout << names[i] << endl;
     }
}

int findName(vector<string> names, string nameToErase)
{
    int return_value = -1;
    names.find()

    return return_value;
}

int main()
{
 vector<string> names;

 addNames(names);

 string nameToErase;
 cin >> nameToErase;

 int indexFound = findName(names, nameToErase);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is std::find method.
Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector< string > v;
    v.push_back( "AAAA" );
    v.push_back( "BBBB" );
    v.push_back( "BBBB1" );
    v.push_back( "BBBB33" );
    vector< string >::iterator i = find( v.begin(), v.end(), "BBBB1" );
    if( i != v.end() )
    {
        cout << "Found " << *i << " on index " << i - v.begin() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. My compiler keeps on telling me that i is an undeclared identifier when I try out your example?

Comment: Show what it tells, which one :). I have pasted whole example I run on my computer :)

Comment: Here is an declaration of std::vector< std::string >::iterator i = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), "BBBB1" );

Comment: I include using namespace std; at the beginning so here's my code.        vector<string> iterator i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), "AAAA");

Comment: @RobertWadowski You failed to `#include <string>` as well as `#include <algorithm>`.  You did have an unnecessary `<memory>`.  Please see this:  http://ideone.com/k95Zjh

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie True, sorry, poject taken from another example

Comment: @Madison Brann vector< string >::iterator i = find( v.begin(), v.end(), "BBBB1" ); instead of vector<string> iterator i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), "AAAA");  "::" between vector< string > and iterator must stay...

Comment: @Madison Brann I have pasted example with using namespace std; to be seen clearly

Comment: okay I got it working. So if I wanted to find the specefic index that the string came from how would I do that?

Comment: @Madison Brann this is your index  i - v.begin(), run program, see it will print you index of found string

Comment: Okay I can print out if I do cout << *i;  Guess what my question is how do I remove the string I found from the vector? so if I had "madison", and "robert" in my vector and I search and find "madison", how do I remove "madison" from the vector?

Comment: @Madison Brann As stated in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase so v.erase( i ); if i != v.end(); Read documentation about what you are using :). std::find returns iterator which can be used with erase method

Comment: Okay thanks! I was doing v.erase(*i). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This method will work

```
void findAndErase(vector<string> & names, string nameToErase) {
    vector<string>::iterator pos = std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), nameToErase);
    if (pos != names.end())
        names.erase(pos);
}
```